# Git: fatal: Needed a single revision even though repo/revision both supplied

Tags: git

I have added a remote "upstream" repo reference to a local clone:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/<owner>/<repo>
```

Then did a remote fetch

```
git fetch upstream -a
```

Then the following attempt to rebase:

```
git rebase upstream/master
```

Gave us:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
```

We can see the upstream:

```
$git branch -r
upstream/master
```

Git status shows us on master:

```
 $git status
 On branch master

 Initial commit

 nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

What is needed here?

Comment: You haven't fetched anything from the remote yet. Try a `git fetch upstream master` first.

Comment: Thx for mentioning that: actually I had done the `git fetch`  - but neglected to mention: the OP has been updated.

Comment: Does `upstream/master` show up when you run `git branch -r`?

Comment: @ChrisMartin  Updated OP for that.

Comment: Are you currently on a branch, or in a detached HEAD state?

Comment: @twalberg  updated OP from `git status` showing on master

Comment: Ah - that "Initial commit" is a clue - your "master" branch does not have any commits on it, so there's nothing to rebase. Probably you did `git init` to create a new repository and then your above commands. If all you want is for "master" to point to the same commit as "upstream/master", you could just `git reset --hard upstream/master` in this case... Generally speaking, there are a number of things that work differently in the case of an "unborn branch" like this...

Comment: @twalberg.  OK . Please make that an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `git status` output:

```
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

indicates that this is a new repository with an "unborn master branch" - no commits have been made.

Because there are no commits on `master` to actually rebase, then `git rebase` should not be expected to work (there are several other caveats or other things that work differently in this "unborn branch" state, as well).

In this case, if your goal is for "master" to reference the same commit as "upstream/master", this is probably the best way to do that:

```
git reset --hard upstream/master
```